# Import files without adding .jsx at the end not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I am working on a react project in which I have imported `.jsx` files without adding the extension `.jsx` at the end. But while I was trying to incorporate typescript files. It stopped identifying files unless the extension is added at the import statement.

```
import Item from "./Item"
//not working

import Item from "./Item.jsx"
//working
```

How can I fix this? where could the problem be?
I use create-react-app

Comment: did you eject your project?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to add typescript into your project if you want to incorporate it.
Now for the extension problem, you can add a webpack.config.js file and include the following in it:

```
{
    module.exports = {
        entry: './index.tsx',
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.tsx']
        }
    }
}
```

this will enable you to import files without extensions.